# where to put interceptor in magento 2

Tags: magento2

Whenever some http request to any of magento page, i would like to trigger to check if there is a param exist in the url. in which file should the code be located in line of best practice?

eg: `http://mymagentosite.com/page/xx?p=123`

if (param p exist) execute function

Comment: you need to go for controller file execute function

Answer (score 0):

You might not need a plugin / interceptor.
I think you can use the event `controller_action_predispatch`.

For this create a file called `events.xml` in your module inside the `etc` folder.

If you want this to happen only for frontend, place the file in `etc/frontend`.

The file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="controller_action_predispatch">
        <observer name="my-predispatch-observer" instance="[Vendor]\[Module]\Observer\ControllerActionPredispatch" />
    </event>
</config>
```

then create the file `Observer/ControllerActionPredispatch.php` inside your module

```
<?php 
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Observer;

class ControllerActionPredispatch implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request */
        $request = $observer->getData('request');
        $p = $request->getParam('p');
        if ($p) {
            //do your magic here
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code so watch out for typos.